# Tags and how do I remove unnecessary tags attached to my profile?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

A few years ago I registered on Stack Overflow as a Ruby on Rails developer.

I wasn't an extremely active user on Stack Overflow, but I did update my profile at the time. When I did, I also added a bunch of Ruby on Rails tags.

I recently came back to be a part of this community. As a part of that I reviewed my profile and saw a lot of unnecessary Ruby on Rails tags.

I'm not really sure what tags are for. Why do we need them or how do we use them on Stack Overflow? Also, how do I remove these tags? I don't develop in Ruby on Rails anymore.

Here is an image of my tags in my profile:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have more activity in the [tag:java-ee] tag since you have 4 posts in that tag.  And the really important number is the one on the left, which is your total answer score for a tag.  Answer score is a good indicator of what subjects you are familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those tags are all the tags you have posted either a question or answer in. For example, if you ask a question with the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tags, those two tags will appear in that list. Note that if you click on one of those tags, it will take you to a search that will show you all the posts you have associated with those tags.

If you hover over the number in front a tag, you will get a tooltip that will tell you how many questions and answers you have in that tag, along with your combined scores for questions and scores for answers. The number in front of a tag is your answer score- The combined score of all your answers in that tag.

[image: Example of tooltip when hovering over the number in front of a tag on a user's profile.]

This image is from your own profile- Note that the tooltip tells you you have 3 questions, the total score for which is -1, int he [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) tag. You also have 1 answer, with a total score of 0, in the same tag.

From personal observation, if only one post is associated with a tag on your profile, and that post becomes dissociated (i.e. the tags are edited and that tag is removed or the post itself is deleted) the tag is removed from your list of tags.

The use of these tags is to help, at a glance, show some of the areas you've interacted in. Some of them may be redundant or irrelevant, but other than the examples I gave, there is no way (that I know of) to remove tags from that list.